# How do I build a C# project which has resources with MSBuild?

Tags: c#, msbuild, resx, csc

I have been trying to build a project with MSBuild which has resource files.  Currently the msbuild instructions that I am trying to use are as follow:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <CSFile Include = "$(WorkingDir)\$(AppName)\**\*.cs" />
    <RXFile Include = "$(WorkingDir)\$(AppName)\**\*.resx" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="AssemblyInfo">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputDirectory)\$(AppName)"/>
    <Message Text="Building..."/>

    <!-- Run the Visual C# compilation using input files of type CSFile -->
    <CSC
        TargetType="winexe"
        DocumentationFile="$(OutputDirectory)\$(AppName)\$(AppName).xml"
        OutputAssembly = "$(OutputDirectory)\$(AppName)\$(AppName).exe"
        Platform="x86" Sources = "@(CSFile)"       
        Resources="@(RXFile)"
        DisabledWarnings="1591" >

    <!-- Set the OutputAssembly attribute of the CSC task to the name of the executable file that is created -->
    <Output TaskParameter = "OutputAssembly" ItemName = "DLLFile" />
    </CSC>

    <!-- Log the file name of the output file -->
    <Message Text="The output file is @(DLLFile)"/>
</Target>
```

This all seems to work when I have a normal resource file.  **However** when I add in an icon into the resource file, the build no longer works - it does not error, it just will not run the application.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong - I have looked through the Internet and everything I have read seems to suggest what I am doing should work.

(I have created a new project which is just a default windows form app, with a button and an icon for the form. the resx file is as follows)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
    <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="metadata">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="assembly">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="data">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="resheader">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <assembly alias="System.Drawing" name="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  <data name="$this.Icon" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
    <value>
        AAABAAEAEBAAAAAAIABoBAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAQAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        AAD///8BoqKiDaKiotmioqL5oqKiK////wH///8B////Af///wH///8B////AaKioiGioqLxoqKi5aKi
        ohn///8B////AbS0tBW0tLTz29vb/7Ozsu18Wi+Be1gswXtYLO17WCzte1gswXtYLIGzs7Lz2dnZ/7S0
        tPu0tLQj////Af///wH///8BxsbGQdPT0//Cv739nGs7/6ZsNf+ubzf/rm83/6ZsNf+hdkr/xcTD/8bG
        xf/GxsY/////Af///wH///8B////AYxlNmejiGn1r3hE/7uMXv/Ck3H/xJF0/8OPcf+/kGz/uIpd/7SG
        Wf+hhWT1jGU2Z////wH///8B////AZZtOzWWbTvVs31G/8KZcf/Yqon/79/P//r28//69fP/79/R/9en
        hf++lGz/s31G/5ZtO9WWbTs1////Af///wGhdUGBsIBK/8abb//Zqoj///7r///67v///fL///7y///8
        7////ev/2aN6/8KZbP+wgEr/oXVBgf///wH///8BrH5Iwb+PWP/No4H/8NvB///35v/68uP/xcC2//Ht
        3v///Oj///Xf/+/Ur//ImXL/v49Y/6x+SMH///8B////AbeHTu3JnGb/z5+A//rz4v/99un/8vDj/42M
        hP+Bf3f/0s/C///76//67Mz/x5Bt/8mcZv+3h07t////Af///wHCkFTtzqZx/9Glif/69un//fju////
        +f+BgHn/sa6k/4F/d//Jxrr/+vDT/8mWcv/OpnH/wpBU7f///wH///8BzZlbwdOsdf/Zt5j/8ePW//77
        9f/19fP/n56V//Dw6f/4+PL/vrmt//Dawv/Sqof/06x1/82ZW8H///8B////AbOddIvTrXf/38Sa/969
        qv//////8PDu/+fl2v////f////3///+8//ctJj/28CW/8Kqfv/Gn2qF////AQCZ3T0KmtjZLpzF9d6/
        iv/iyaf/37+u//Hj3P/z8ez/9PHr//Hi2f/cuqP/38Oe/4yxqf84ptH5DprWzwCZ3ScAoON9fNHy7WHD
        6O86pMb74seS/+bRqf/gwqb/1a6W/9Wrkv/evaD/5M+m/7/Bnv9Hstf9q+P2/Smw6NkAoOMnAKfpe13J
        8eW16Pn/Ycfr7zqqzPPsxIj/6cuU/+fQnf/n0J3/6cuU/97Cjv8yqtD1gdPw9XPQ8+sAp+nNAKfpBQCu
        7wUAru+LW8v05b/s+v9cy/HpTbLJxfq8dMH6vHTt+rx07fq8dMFRssjDac/y7XzW9u0Aru/JAK7vHf//
        /wH///8BALX0AwC19IEAtfTRALX0ywC19Af///8B////Af///wH///8BALX0FwC19NEAtfTJALX0J///
        /wH///8BAAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA
        //8AAP//AAD//w==
</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

Comment: Do you not have a csproj file that you can point msbuild at?

Comment: Yes I do, however, I don't want to build with the project as it's meant for a build server and I don't want files which are not in the project file to be missed or to try and find files that have been added but the developer has not added the file into the build

Comment: Don't tend to mess with MSBuild much, but shouldn't the icon be included in the project/msbuild file as an EmbeddedResource? See EmbeddedResource at [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx) If you were doing this in Visual studio you'd just change the build action of the icon to Embedded Resource.

Comment: @Chris arguably, if the developer has forgotten to add file to the project then you have bigger problems ;) Has the 'easier method' actually demonstrated this problem? Ideally, a given configuration should build on your server in the same form that the developers build on their machines. Things are more testable that way.

Comment: What version of the framework is the project targeting? What version of the framework tools are you using?

Comment: @James S - I have tried using the embedded resource but it just does not work - I still have the same problem.

Comment: @mikez I am targeting .Net 4